# Pygame help needed

Tags: python, text, pygame

**I am new to PyGame and need some help!**
Let me start of by saying that I have a basic understanding of the Python language, I recently started learning how to use PyGame as well as it was something new to me. However I do get stuck quite a lot when trying to code for PyGame. *Just so that you know I have read and watched a lot of tutorials but none of them helps me in the way I need it to.*

My problem is that I am trying to get a box to appear on the screen that has a word written on it, such as: "Hello". Once that button is clicked then hello should appear.

Here is my plan:

- I make a *class* named *pane*
- Properties of that class would be things like: xpos, ypos, text, width height
- Methods of that class would be things like: add(textToDisplay), delete(textToDisplay) - (The delete function is currently not all that important), displayPane()

If possible could you please tell me if this is actually doable using python and pygame/sort of hint to me how I would do it  (Like with some useful links because Google has not been my friend for when it has come down to the searching. XD )? and if it isn't what language would you recommend I do it in?

Comment: If I do not reply to any comments instantly it's because I am probably in bed. As it is fairly late where I live. :)

Comment: Yes this is possible in Pygame. But your question is really vague. What concept are you having trouble with exactly?

Comment: I can't create the box class (I just need to create a box that has something written on it, something like hello, and then that needs to appear on the screen)  Oh and thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos
http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint
http://pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect
http://pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont

My suggestion is a procedural approach if you're dealing with only one shape:

- Use `pygame.draw.rect` to draw a rectangle on a point.
- Use a function to capture mouse clicks and their positions.
- Collide mouse clicks
  with you rectangle position (use a list of objects if you have
  several).
- Create a function to draw text on the screen and associate
  it with the function which collides mouse clicks to rectangles.

Otherwise I'd take an object-oriented approach and use the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) class for each shape, or custom classes if you have special needs. The click capture-and-colide part would still be procedural, of course.

I adapted a project I'm working on to do what I think is what you want:

[image]

*You can't actually see the cursor but I'm clicking with the middle mouse button to create the circles and with the main button to display the text.*

Source: http://pastebin.com/jycEFAtX

Note: It's a circle and not a rectangle because I was working with circles, but that should be easy for you to change. Everything is a mess because I just adapted what I had and put it all together on a single file (it's probably better to separate it into different files). Use it just to get an idea of how to do what you want.

You can delete the text by setting `obj.text` as `None`, for example when `event.button == SECONDARY_BUTTON`, that way you can delete the text by clicking with the secondary mouse button on the circles.

**P.S.:** Notice I have a function that collides objects with mouse position (because it's needed for what I'm working with), but you don't need that. You can use `pygame.Rect` and `pygame.Rect.collidepoint`, as suggested above.

Comment: Thank you so much these are the kind of links and helps that I really needed. Thank you.

Comment: Again I'd like to thank you for all your help but I just can't get my head around anything. This project is killing me :(. Thing is i just need to __draw a rectangle__ in __pygmae__ with __"hello"__ written in it using __classes__. To me it seems so easy but when i come to do it I just can't do it.